# storing contents in vectors in C++ language

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How do you store contents in a vector and then sort them without creating a class? 
Doing a class project and it requires to not use a class. The books are not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) page has a good example, assuming you can put all of the elements in the vector at once. If you need to put them in one at a time, use std::vector::push_back.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `std::vector<std::string> v; v.push_back("hello"); std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());`.  Get better books.